# Unexpected null values from CompletableFuture execution

Tags: java

I need to run a lot o REST calls and save results.
To speed things up I want to do it parallel.
Following code is usually working but sometimes I'm getting null value in result list (always on first position).
Any idea why this is happening?

And second question.
It there a better way to do this task (parallel REST calls)?

```
List<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();
CompletableFuture.allOf(ids.stream()
    .map(id -> asyncRestService.fetchResult(id)
        .exceptionally(e -> {
            log.error("error id: " + id, e);
            return new Result();
        })
        .thenAccept(result::add))
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new)
).join();

log.debug("Result: " + result);
```

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Result> fetchResult(String id) {
    Result result = new Result();
    // adding something to result
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
}
```

Comment: Add some code showing the input, actual and desired output or better a [Minimal, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Do you necessary need to call `fetchResult` by only passing a single id each time? More productive would be to make a call passing a collection of all ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure whether this is the code's main issue or not, but it may definitely cause the behaviour you've described above.

You're accessing `result` in a non-thread-safe manner as `ArrayList` is an unsynchronized data structure.

Imagine that two threads are completing the requests they are handling at the same time. As the lambda passed to `CompletableFuture#thenAccept(Consumer<? super T>)` is executed by the thread that completes the future, the `ArrayList#(E)` function might also be called in parallel. This may lead to inconsistent results, as a quick glance at the source code of `ArrayList#add(E)` shows:

```java
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

As `element` is of type `Object[]`, this operation isn't thread-safe and may lead to data races. The same is true for `size`. Even if we assume that every change to `size` (and `element`) is available to any other thread, this still wouldn't work as `size++` is a non-atomic operation despite `size`s data type (reads and writes to variables of type `int` [are atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7), but `size++` consists of multiple read and write operations).

Comment: It was source of problem. Changing to `Collections.synchronizedList()` solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. However, instead of using a synchronized list, you may also just call `CompletableFuture#join` in e.g. a `peak`-operation inside your stream and collect the results afterwards. By this, you avoid the overhead coming with an additional, synchronized data source. Furthermore, lambdas should generally be stateless. By "letting the stream collecting the data for you", you can achieve exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

try init result with CopyOnWriteArrayList which is thread-safe list

`List<Label> items = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();`